# How to add url link with its image or fetching with its image using normal html and css? (Share link with metadata in social media)

Tags: html, css

I want to do the thing which is shown in this image

[image]

If you see in the above image the container contains the link URL and image which is fetched from that URL...
How it is achieved using HTML and CSS?

Comment: I couldn't really found out what you looking for. You want to whenever you share your website link in social media's your website fav and description appear with it?

Comment: yes when we share anything on social media its link is shared with the image which is on the link...

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Comment: Actually I don't have much knowledge of open graphs and I want to ask that there is only one way to do this? or this can be implemented by any other way

Comment: The open graph protocol is the only way that exists until today to share data with social media about your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to achieve such a thing **you need to use [the open graph protocol](https://ogp.me/) meta tags in your HTML `<head>`**, to enable social media graph read your metadata. There are several tags that are available within the open graph protocol but the main ones are:

- `og:title`: The title of your object as it should appear within the graph, e.g., "The Rock".
- `og:type`: The type of your object, e.g., "video.movie". Depending on the type you specify, other properties may also be required.
- `og:image`: An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.
- `og:url`: The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".

```html
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

**NOTE** From the moment that you add these meta tags to your HTML `<head>` it may take a while *(1-2 weeks)* until they get read by social media graphs.

Comment: You can use FB's [OG Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to flush their cache out. Good answer though.